# Calculating area of raster for value range using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, area

I need to know the area occupied by values between 0.2 and 0.8 for my raster

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1813, 1883, 3413879  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002704818, 0.0002704818  (x, y)
extent      : 31.64487, 32.15419, 0.1148583, 0.6052419  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : -0.974359, 0.8222222  (min, max)
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? Should be pretty straight forward. Get the number of cells and multiply by resolution. Get the average length of one degree at your location and multiply it with your resolution. If the numbers need to be more exact you need to project to a local coordinate system.

Comment: How do i get to know the number of cells whose values range between 0.2 and 0.8

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Why are you showing R output? If you are already in R, you can easily do this via a bracket query, without reclassifying the raster, which would be necessary in ArcGIS. The R approach to pulling the number of cells in the data range is simply: length(x[x >= 0.2 & x <= 0.8])

Answer (score 2):

use the "reclassify" tool in spatial analyst to create a class of NDWI values between 0.2 and 0.8 (also posssible with raster calculator, e.g. Con(("ndwi_raster" >= 0.2) AND ("ndwi_raster" <= 0.8), 1, 0)

This should a raster attribute table automatically. Otherwise you can use "create raster attribute table".

Once this is done, open the raster attribute table to have the count.

Remark: your NDWI seems to suffer from a tiling effect.